# Using something similar to OFFSET for return type Range

Tags: vba, excel, loops, offset, do-while

> I want to create a Do While ... Loop that will step through each cell
>   in a column and check to see if the value in each cell is a number. It should also keep a count of how many numbers there are before the first non-number entry

But, I don't know what technique to use to step down cell-by-cell... this is what I had first tried (it is simplified and assumes there are numbers in column A starting from row 1 down to an arbitrary row):

```
Counter = 0
Iteration = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

Do While IsNumeric(Iteration) = True And IsEmpty(Iteration) = False
   Counter = Counter + 1
   Iteration = Iteration.Offset(1,0)
Loop
```

However, this doesn't work because Offset(1,0) returns the value within the referenced cell. So, I need something similar to Offset but with a return value of type Range. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Declare Iteration as Range and Set it.

And the count is not needed:

```
Dim Iteration as Range

Set Iteration = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

Do While IsNumeric(Iteration.Value) And Iteration.Value <> ""
   Set Iteration = Iteration.Offset(1,0)
Loop
```

Comment: Ahhh... so Offset CAN return a range, but because I have not explicitly declared iteration as type Range it implicitly assigned it some type of number? Also, I just edited my question to include the fact that I need to keep count of how many numbers there are hence my inclusion of counter.

Comment: It put the value of `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` in Iteration and it would be a number.  Then the Offset would not work.  @DavidSouth

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks Scott. One last question: If I use your exact answer but remove the "Set" in the loop the program does not crash but the address of Iteration is never updated by the offset. Why is this?

Comment: @DavidSouth Range is an Object as as such it must be Set.  Otherwise you get the value and not the cell itself.  As to get the count.  If all you want is the count of cell that have numbers in them this one line will do it `Counter =Application.WorksheetFormula.Count(Range("A:A"))` no loops needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub checkNumber()

    For x = 2 To Range("a65536").End(xlUp).Row
        If IsNumeric(Range("a" & x).Value) Then
            Range("b" & x).Value = "this is a number"
        Else
            Range("b" & x).Value = "this is not a number"
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```